# jQuery returns window object

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a really stupid question, but for the life of me I can't understand:

Why  `$(button).addClass('focus')` returns DOMNodes

but

`(button.addClass || $(button).addClass)('focus')` returns the `Window` object ?

EDIT: Is this linked to JavaScript indirect calls, like : `(1, alert)('test')` ?

Comment: What is button, and what are you trying to do?  It looks like you're overcomplicating things.

Comment: Button can be a DOMNode or a jQuery wrapped DOMNode.

Comment: You'd be best making it be one or the other and putting it in a function where you can either pass `button` (as a jQuery object) or `$(button)` if it's a DOM element, so the function is always dealing with the same type.  But anyway, that's not your question is it :p

Comment: I know how to solve the problem. The issue is more why do these these two cases return the values they do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you essentially are doing is this:

```
var fn;
if (button.addClass)
    fn = button.addClass;
else
    fn = $(button).addClass;
fn('focus');
```

Hence, you lose the reference to either button or $(button).

Comment: Since it's the answer, i'll format it for future reference

Answer (score 3):

jQuery functions can be chained. This is done by putting `return this;` at the end of its functions.

However, when you do `(button.addClass || $(button).addClass)('focus')`, you are dereferencing the function and its context is lost. `window` is the default context (unless you're in Strict Mode, in which case I think it's `null` (but as a non-Strict Mode user, I don't know for sure)) which is why you get the `Window` back.

Also any attempt to chain this function would fail.

Comment: I know about chaining, but why does a `logical OR` and `() parenthesis` dereference the context ? Shouldn't the caller define the reference ? Like: `a.b()` and `b.b()` ?

Comment: I... can't answer that, sorry. I just know that's what happens, not why.

Comment: @m_vdbeek: If you write `foo.bar()` or `foo["bar"]()` then `bar` will be called with `this` equal to `foo`. In **any other case** (barring specific exceptions) `this` will be equal to the global object (`window`).